# Identificar de qual partição está rodando o script

Tags: windows, cmd, batch, ms-dos, 32-bits

No caso do `prompt` de comando podemos usar as variáveis de ambiente do Windows pra adiantar caminhos, como:

```
echo %homedrive%
```

Que vai resultar na letra de atributo onde o `sistema operacional` foi instalado.

Mas pra falar a verdade eu nunca pensei em precisar saber de onde o Batch estaria rodando, desde que ele alcançasse o caminho certo. O que quero é impedir que o Script seja rodado pelo usuário acessando outra máquina (unidade mapeada) ou direto de um pen-drive.

```
IF %HOMEDRIVE% == LOCAL_DA_SCRIPT (
   goto INICIAR
) ELSE (
   echo NAO PERMITIDO, ENCERRE O SCRIPT OU PECA AJUDA
   echo PARA O SUPORTE TECNICO
   pause>nul
)
```

Comment: acho que pode ajudar: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24101703/4713574

Comment: Eu dei uma boa lida nisto, mas não é bem o que preciso.

Comment: pensei que poderia executar o script em partições secundárias por exemplo, aí teria que verificar se a unidade onde está sendo executada é do tipo `Local Fixed Disk` independente da letra ou se está na mesma unidade do SO. Mas sua solução é adequada, muito bom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu consegui, o comando `cd` já que ele também é uma variável:

```
echo %cd%
rem Exemplo Windows XP: C:\Document and Settings\{currentuser}
rem Exemplo Windows 7: C:\Users\{currentuser}
```

Para pegar só a partição:

```
echo %cd:~0,2%
rem Exemplo: C:
```

Então pra fazer a comparação:

```
IF %HOMEDRIVE% EQU %cd:~0,2% ( goto INICIAR ) ELSE ( goto ERRO )

:INICIAR
rem INICIO DO SCRIPT
pause

:ERRO
echo VOCE NAO PODE INICIAR O SCRIPT DE DENTRO
echo DO PENDRIVE OU MAPA VIRTUAL COPIE OS ARQUIVOS
echo PARA O SEU DESKTOP OU ALGUMA PASTADO SEU SISTEMA
pause>nul
exit
```

Comment: Você também pode salvar o **cd** num arquivo `txt` `cd>drivecurrent.txt` e depois recuperar numa variavel `set /p atual=<drivecurrent.txt` e aí sim você reparte o conteúdo dela %atual:~0,2%. Mas a sua maneira ficou bem mais simples